# Jquery datepicker format not working at all

Tags: jquery-ui

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ format: 'yy-mm-dd' });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code from jquery UI website.

And like you can see, this format doesn't work at all!

do you know why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The property is incorrect ... instead of `format` should be `dateFormat`:

So, instead of:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ format: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

Should be:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

API reference [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).